# Cable jack melted

Tags: power, safety, cables, short-circuit, constant-current

I've build this circuit:

[image]

My power supply is 12 V, 4 A and my load is rated at 1 A and the melting point of the cable I'm using is 300 F.

I found the cable has melted at the point of contact between the two and has fused together. I'm trying to understand why.

I found a short in the circuit, but shouldn't that cause the whole whole cable to burn/melt rather than one specific point? Could somebody let me know why this happened?

Comment: Let me do my always dodgy calculation. Ohm's Law says 12V / 300Ω = 0.04A. But wait a minute: Did you say 300F, not 300Ω? 300F is a very big cap, so the start current is very big, therefore melts you stuff.

Comment: @tlfong01 the OP said the melting point of the wire is 300F.  It's a temperature rating, not a capacitor in the circuit.

Comment: If you have a particularly bad connection, the connection can behave as a resistor. You can calculate the power dissipation if the point of contact was, for example, a 0.5 ohm resistor. By the way the load is probably not 300 ohms.

Comment: @mkeith I would imagine they're talking about the insulation rating being 300F. They probably meant that the cable insulation has melted allowing the wires to touch and fuse together.

Answer (score 1):

Connectors always have some contact resistance, in addition to the inherent resistance of the metals.  Over time, as the contacts corrode or become contaminated, that resistance can increase.  Wires, on the other hand, are generally solid copper from one end to the other (even if plated and/or insulated).  The resistance is not only low, but distributed over the whole length.

If you have even 1-2 ohms of resistance in the connector, and short the (4A) load, the connector will be dissipating substantially more power (16-32W given these numbers) per unit surface area, and will heat up proportionally.  Your momentary short probably overtaxed the connector, while only warming up the wires for a few seconds.

Answer (score 1):

The cable has a resistance, and if the cable and load have a connector between them, there is a contact resistance at the connector. If you soldered the cable to your load, then the connector is the solder, which still has contact resistance. The contact resistance for a power connector is typically 100 mOhm or less, which may or may not be greater than the cable resistance.

If R1 is shorted, then the power supply tries to output as much current as it can. 4 A in your case. The cable will heat up, and the connector will heat up. Which causes the cable insulation to fail first depends on the cable resistance versus contact resistance, and the thermal boundary conditions.  In general it's the connector that fails first. The cable has a low resistance, and there is a lot of area for the heat to dissipate by convection. A connector dissipates it's heat over a small area, so it heats up faster.

Comment: also note a power supply designed for 4A might be able to output more than 4A, for a short time (perhaps it will go bang after a short time)